# Importing the Resin source into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resin, quercus

How can I import the Resin source code into Eclipse (3.6)? I'm looking to edit some main functions of Quercus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've 'svn checkout' the code from the svn location found on the bottom of the [main page](http://quercus.caucho.com/) and then from Eclipse `Import` > `Existing Projects into Workspace` and I can successfully see the Quercus code.

Comment: How would I put Quercus back into Resin if I do it this way? Isn't there any way to load the Resin source code?